# Golang Extract ECDH Private Key

Tags: go, encryption, ecdsa, ecdh

I know that ECDH private key is a superset of public key. The task is to extract private key ecdh.

Here is the way how to generate PublicKey:

```
    import (
        "crypto/ecdh"
        "crypto/rand"
        "crypto/ecdsa"
        "crypto/x509"
        "encoding/base64"
        "encoding/pem"
        "fmt"
)


func main() {

        alicePrivateKey, err := ecdh.P256().GenerateKey(rand.Reader)
        alicePublicKey, err := MarshalECDHPublicKey(alicePrivateKey.PublicKey())  
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Errorf("failed to marshal public key into PKIX format")
        }

        fmt.Printf("alicePubK => %s\n", alicePublicKey)

    clientECDSAPubKey, err := UnmarshalECDSAPublicKey(alicePublicKey)
    if err != nil {
       panic(err)
    }
    println(clientECDSAPubKey)
    println("no error")

}  

func MarshalECDHPublicKey(pk *ecdh.PublicKey) (string, error) {
        ecdhSKBytes, err := x509.MarshalPKIXPublicKey(pk)
        if err != nil {
                return "", fmt.Errorf("failed to marshal public key into PKIX format")
        }
        ecdhSKPEMBlock := pem.EncodeToMemory(
                &pem.Block{
                        Type:  "PUBLIC KEY",
                        Bytes: ecdhSKBytes,
                },
        )

        return base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(ecdhSKPEMBlock), nil
}
```

Comment: The code is incomplete, the implementation of `UnmarshalECDSAPublicKey()` is missing. If the call of this function is not needed for your problem, you should remove it, otherwise add the implementation.

Comment: If by *extract* you actually mean *export*, you should use `x509.MarshalPKCS8PrivateKey()` (for the PKCS#8 format). BTW, in `MarshalECDHPublicKey()` the exported PEM key is Base64 encoded, which is pointless and rather a bug (a PEM encoded key is already a string, so why Base64 encode it again?).

Comment: Your question is confusing! Here you want `The task is to extract private key ecdh.` but `clientECDSAPubKey, err := UnmarshalECDSAPublicKey(alicePublicKey)` does contradict the prior statement. 

To let you know it's not computationally feasible to extract private key from the public key, that's the whole point of cryptography.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you want to extract `ecdh` private key in `pem` format just like you did with the public key. Extracting private key from the public key isn't possible (computationally not feasible).  I've implemented the `UnmarshalECDSAPublicKey` function for you (better renamed as `MarshalECDHPrivateKey`)

```
// MarshalPKCS8PrivateKey converts a private key to PKCS #8, ASN.1 DER form.
//
// The following key types are currently supported: *rsa.PrivateKey,
// *ecdsa.PrivateKey, ed25519.PrivateKey (not a pointer), and *ecdh.PrivateKey.
// Unsupported key types result in an error.
//
// This kind of key is commonly encoded in PEM blocks of type "PRIVATE KEY".
func UnmarshalECDSAPublicKey(alicePrivateKey *ecdh.PrivateKey) (string, error) {
    ecdhSKBytes, err := x509.MarshalPKCS8PrivateKey(alicePrivateKey)
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("failed to marshal private key into PKIX format")
    }

    ecdhSKPEMBlock := pem.EncodeToMemory(
        &pem.Block{
            Type:  "PRIVATE KEY",
            Bytes: ecdhSKBytes,
        },
    )
    return string(ecdhSKPEMBlock), nil
}
```

As others pointed in the comments about `MarshalECDHPublicKey` function, you don't need to encode again with `base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(ecdhSKPEMBlock)` as `pem.EncodeToMemory` does the same, you can just convert that to string.